# How to view my coded controls in the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I create labels in my form in C# Visual Studio 2010, in code not with the designer. I can see the labels when the program runs but they are not visible in the designer. Can I make them visible? Or only controls created in the designer by drag and drop are visible?

Thanks

Comment: If you add them in code, then why do you think the designer would have any idea about them? They don't exist at design time, so the designer will have no clue.

Answer (score 4):

Your Controls are only visible in the designer if you create them in the `InitializeComponent` method. If you drag controls on the form, visual studio does that too in this method.

More Informations: [C# InitializeComponent Explanation](http://www.dotnetperls.com/initializecomponent)

Answer (score 1):

Only controls created in the designer by drag and drop are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago I created a 'plug-in' for a visual studio that created controls from the inside the editor that were there just as you would drag & drop them manually.

What worked as some kind of a prototype, and I never managed to get it to work right and bug-free, so it remained a tool that I only used, and was abandoned after several months.

So, my answer would be - you could do such a thing, but there is a lot of work involved other then just new-ing the Labels and placing it on the form from code.

Here is something that is about ASP.NET, but same principle applies...

http://forums.asp.net/t/279786.aspx/1